# Constantly display status line in less

Tags: less

I know I can have less show me the status line with `=`. Is there a way to have it displayed constantly and updated as I scroll through the file? When I use `man` it's actually done this way but I don't know how it's configured.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to change the prompt (as it's called), `-P` is probably what you want (quote from [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less)):

> -Pprompt or --prompt=prompt
>   Provides a way to tailor the three prompt styles to your own preference.
>    `-Ps` followed by a string changes the default (short) prompt to that string. `-Pm` changes the medium (-m) prompt. `-PM` changes the long (-M) prompt. [...]  See the section on PROMPTS for more details.

There's a bunch of variables you can use presented in the section on prompts. On my system, the `=` prompt displays lines and bytes, so let's set the `$LESS` variable to show lines and bytes that are visible on the screen in the short (default) prompt:

```
$ LESS='-Pslines %lt-%lb (%Pt-%Pb \%) bytes %bt-%bb file %f' ; export LESS
$ less foo
```

displays a prompt like `lines 1-44 (1-53 %) bytes 0-2498 file foo`

(`%l`, `%P`, `%b` for lines, percentage and bytes, trailing `t` and `b` for "top" and "bottom" of screen. `%`, `?`, `:`, `.` and `\` are special and need to be escaped.)

The default prompt also has conditionals to not show fields that are unknown, and also to show `(END)` instead of `100%` at the end of file. As an example, the latter can be done with
`?e(END):%pB\%.`.

Comment: `(END)` is done with `?e`. You can see the default prompt by typing `-P` and hitting enter. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The `-M` option (also `--LONG-PROMPT`) does this.

A few variations are listed in the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less):

> **`-m`** or **`--long-prompt`**
> Causes less to prompt verbosely (like more), with the percent into the file. By default, less prompts with a colon.
>
> **`-M`** or **`--LONG-PROMPT`**
> Causes less to prompt even more verbosely than more.

Comment: `-M` surprisingly doesn't seem very verbose at all, just showed current lines vs. bytes from `-m` for my piped data.

Comment: Is the `-M` format not standardized?  For me, `-M` gives me filename, line range, and percentage.  `-m` only gives me percentage, nothing else.